# Вызов функции о определенным аргументом JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть вот такая функция с тремя аргументами.

```
    function errorLog(checkedLink, _statusCode, errorText) {
    var _errorLog = "URL: " + checkedLink+"\nStatus Code: " +_statusCode+"\nJSPError: " + errorText
  console.log(_errorLog);
}
```

Нужно вызвать ее лишь с одним определенным аргументом.
Попробовал вот так:

```
errorLog(errorText = data.match(reg)[1]);
```

Ошибок не получил, но функция отработала так будто я передал первый аргумент. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как сделать правильно?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
errorLog(null, null, data.match(reg)[1]);
```

А можно использовать деструктуризацию:

```js
function errorLog({checkedLink, _statusCode, errorText}) {
  var _errorLog = "URL: "+checkedLink+"\nStatus Code: "+_statusCode+"\nJSPError: "+errorText;
  console.log(_errorLog);
}

errorLog({errorText: 'Error text'});
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо!